# NHibernate SaveOrUpdate takes ages

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, .net-6.0

I have a dataset to be inserted into an mssql db using NHibernate on dotnet6 using c#.
The dataset contains nearly 8k entries to be inserted or updated in the db. Code looks like this.

```
public void Execute<T>(IEnumerable<T> layouts)
    {
        using (Session = mSessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                foreach (T layout in layouts)
                {
                    Session.SaveOrUpdate(layout);
                }
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

(Using the build-in profiler of vs22 I can observe that each entry takes about 80ms: 8000/(1000/80)=640s/60=10min)
**Calling this method with an array of layouts (the dataset) takes about 10~15minuts!**
I cant imagine this taking so long given the fact that there is only one referenced table connected to the main table in the database.

Am I missing something?

Comment: ORMs aren't really designed for bulk inserts, at least not for doing them in a performant way. I would recommend calling `SaveOrUpdate` in batches though. For example, every 100 records.

Comment: Ok, i will test that solution. Without looking into the api, do you have a quick code example for batch updates?

Comment: Since you are using .NET 6, you can use the `Chunk` method: `foreach(var chunk in layouts.Chunk(100)) {  ... }` for example.

Comment: Also try use `OpenStatelessSession` to speed things up.

Comment: Is the id generated by the database?

Comment: Yes the id is generated in the db

Comment: That means each saveorupdate will access the database to get the id. Use hilo or seqhilo to speed up the process. Then SaveOrUpdate can create the id clientside and this saves a lot of roundtrips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
int i = 0;
                foreach (T layout in layouts)
                {
                    Session.SaveOrUpdate(layout);
                    i++;
                    if (i % 20 == 0)
                    {
                        Session.Flush();
                        Session.Clear();
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
                tx.Commit();
```

performance increased a lot.